# Trouble adding element with text to DOM tree

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created an unordered list of elements and I'm trying to add a new element using DOM manipulation.

```
var newEl = document.create Element('li');
var newText = document.createTextNode('Hawaii');
var newEl = newEl.appendChild(newText);
document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0].appendChild(newEl);
```

The element was added to the ul element but it was not added as an li element, so my new text doesn't have any bulleting.

Answer (score 3):

This line

```
    var newEl = newEl.appendChild(newText);
```

Change to

```
    newEl.appendChild(newText);
```

When you reassign it its not the li anymore (this is not JQ)

Answer (score 2):

.appendChild returns the appended element. In this case your newEl will be a text node after this assignment.

```
var newEl = newEl.appendChild(newText);
```

You should remove the assignment and it is fine.

Answer (score 2):

avoid the reassignment to newEl.

```js
var newEl = document.createElement('LI');
var newText = document.createTextNode('Hawaii');
newEl.appendChild(newText);
document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0].appendChild(newEl);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.
Set an id to your ul element and append your new li in ul tag

```js
 var node = document.createElement("li");
 var textnode = document.createTextNode("Hawaii");
 node.appendChild(textnode);  
document.getElementById("myList").appendChild(node);
```

```html
<ul id="myList">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Itm 2</li>
</ul>
```